# How to describe element having more than one value in xml ? <indian_criketer> sachin,rahul,ganguly</indian_criketer> is correct?

Tags: xml

How to describe element having more than one value in xml ?
e.g
  indian criketer  are more  than one name so to store data about it how can we store

is following tag is correct

< indian_criketer> sachin,rahul,ganguly

Answer (score 7):

Generally, you would use an outer wrapping element for your list and an inner element for the values:

```
<cricketers>
  <cricketer>sachin</cricketer>
  <cricketer>rahul</cricketer>
  <cricketer>ganguly</cricketer>
</cricketers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not wrong, but it will be difficult for you to list cricketers if you use the approach that you are using. So the easier way is this one:

```
<indian_criketer_list>
 <cricker_name>sachine</cricker_name>
 <cricker_name>rahul</cricker_name>
 <cricker_name>ganguly</cricker_name>
</indian_criketer_list>
```

Comment: duplicate answer..you could have just upvoted the above answer

Comment: It would be best to put "indian" as an attribute instead of a name tag, oif we want to be pedantic about our XML design :)
I'm kind of assuming other people play cricket outside of India :)

Comment: ya i could have upvoted the above answer, but i only see that answer after writing my answer. :S